# Rails4 - Loop through polymorphic resource in join table with ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphism

1- I have a User (devise) resource which can organize Events and create Partners profiles, then add them to the Event. A User has_many Partners, then Partner can be added to an Event.

2- Partner & User are two differents resource, as partner do not have to have a password, activation email, and can not log in.

3- User can invite other Users to an Event. This has for effect to check if partner with same email exists, then take the lead on partner existing data if it is the case.

4- User can ordering Event attendees (Users+Partners)

For now, I only succeed in steps 1, 2 and 4.
I use a join table events_partners to save attendees and ordering.

How can I manage the invite of a User to an Event ?
I might add polymorphism to the join table, or maybe a simple "id_user" row which is filed when User accepted invite.

But is this the best way to go or do I miss something ?
And, in the view, what is the best way to deal with the loop that print all the attendees of an event (since User and Partners are differents resource and have differents attributes but still are in a main ordered list).

```
"events_partners"
 t.integer  "event_id",    null: false
 t.integer  "partner_id",  null: false
 t.integer  "row_order"

"partners"
t.string   "firstname"
t.string   "lastname"
t.string   "email",  default: "", null: false

"users"
t.string   "firstname"
t.string   "lastname"
t.integer  "phone"
t.string   "url"
t.string   "language"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
...
```

Thank you very much for your help